# Application targeting .NET 4.6.1 seems to run in 4.5.2 compatibility mode in VS 2015 debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6.1

I have a simple console application targeting .NET 4.6.1:

```
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
</startup>
```

The code is as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Security protocols: {0:F}", ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

I run this app via "Start Debugging" and "Start Without Debugging" in Visual Studio 2015. I expect both to write

```
Security protocols: Tls, Tls11, Tls12
```

However, for some reason I get this when in debug mode:

```
Security protocols: Ssl3, Tls
```

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Comment: Hmya, nobody is going to get a repro from that snippet.  The .config entry is not conclusive, the [TargetFrameworkAttribute] embedded in the assembly sets the effective target and thus the default.  Which can get muddled when the project references other assemblies with other targets.  Have a look-see with ildasm.exe.  And beware that the selection can be overridden with a registry key (SchUseStrongCrypto).  And consider just selecting the ones you want.

Comment: @HansPassant, the repro is simple. Just take machine with .NET >= 4.6, don't override any `SchUseStrongCrypto`, create brand-new console application, set target framework, and here you are. I've run ildasm both for app's binary and app's `vshost.exe`. The former seems to target .NET 4.6.1, while the latter targets 4.5, hence the difference. The main question to me is whether this is bug in VS 2015, or a feature. I have some code that depends on SecurityProtocol return value and this is freaky when the same code runs differently under debugger vs. standing alone (and even compiled with DEBUG).

Comment: Well, smells like you found the troublemaker.  Still doesn't get me a repro, but you certainly ought to try Project > Properties > Debug tab > untick "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process".   Be sure you got all the VS2015 updates, the hosting process was pretty buggy in the RTM release.  Do try another machine next.

Comment: @HansPassant, turning off hosting process does the trick. I get a repro on VS2015 with Update 3, version 14.0.25431.01, .NET Framework version 4.7.02046. I will try this workaround on my office PC (that's where I noticed the problem first)

Comment: .NET 4.7, uh-oh.  I'm going to keep Creator edition off my machine as long as humanly possible, the amount of nasty trouble it has been causing is very scary.

Comment: @HansPassant, not sure if it has something to do with VS 2015 debugging. The initial repro was on machine with 4.6.2